# Android Studio Emulator Stuck at Google Logo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, qemu

I am Trying to Running My App in Android Studio Emulator, Emulator Has Been Opened But Stuck At Google logo Loading. What Can I Do? How Can I Run Emulator Fastly, MY PC is Low-End.
I also Decrease the Size of the Ram In Emulator Settings But That's Not Solve MY Problem.
Please Help ME How Can I Run Android Studio Emulator Fast In Low-End Pc

Comment: try changing the system image and phone skin

Comment: well I try Thanks For Response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use the Virtual Device with the Play Store logo on it. Rather choose a virtual device without that play store logo. ( This worked in my case )

[image]

2. Install HAXM from SDK Manager.
3. Wipe out the data from the emulator and re-run it.

One of these might help.

Comment: Thanks For Your Response, I also Try To install Haxm In My Laptop using SDK Manager But I have an error from that because I am using AMD Driver Well I try Other Instruction From You .

Comment: HAXM is for intel processors only

Comment: HAXM definitely helped in my case

Comment: Mine was auto-closing on the Google Boot logo, tried the first point first, worked! (Android Studio Hedgehog 2023)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue where my emulator was stuck on the Google logo or splash screen. Remember, I'm not using Android Studio to run emulators; I'm working on VS Code. To fix the problem of the emulator, follow these three commands in your command prompt (CMD). I hope this will be helpful for both Android Studio and VS Code users.

Three Steps to Fix the Android Emulator Issue (Stuck at Splash Screen):

1. emulator -list-avds
2. emulator -avd YourAVDName -wipe-data
3. emulator -avd YourAVDName

Answer (score 0):

Go to Virtual Device Manager, tap the 3 dots at the far right of the AVD in question and click Edit. Change the Graphics to Software.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue

the easiest solution is to wipe the data
you can open your Android studio and open any random project in it.
then go to Tools -> Device Manager -> select 3 dots on the emulator you want to fix and click on wipe data