# How to fix Android emulator with image above API 30 stuck on google logo on linux

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I have been trying to create an emulator with an emulator image above API 30 but every time I launch the emulators, they get stuck on Google logo.

[image]

When I wait I get the error on the image bellow:

[image]

I have tried to create AVD's with or without the PlayStore icon. And I have also tried to pick devices with all kinds of screen resolutions. I have launched the emulator from both Android Studio & the terminal. None of the solutions I have found like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529759/android-studio-emulator-stuck-at-google-logo) have worked for me.

Devices with image API <= 30 work fine.

My system is a Fedora, Linux with 16gig ram & Core I3 intel processor

Comment: Nope, I m still stuck with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just switched to **cold boot** in advanced settings.

Comment: this worked for me as well. 
I also increased ram from advanced settings