# Android Emulator is stuck on google logo

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator

I've recently updated android studio to Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2 , at first everything was going fine but then the emulator started to get stuck on google logo each time I launch it and I get this error:

[image]

Currently I'm using a Nexus 6 device with Pie operating system.

Solutions that I've tried:

1. installing another device Nexus 6P and Nexus One
2. creating a Nexus 6 device with R operating system
3. using software and automatic graphics rendering
4. using cold boot as mentioned in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74659582/how-to-fix-android-emulator-with-image-above-api-30-stuck-on-google-logo-on-linu)
5. solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529759/android-studio-emulator-stuck-at-google-logo)
6. decreasing RAM to 512 MB

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: no I've started to used a physical device instead @Junaid